# The class must be declared abstract error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am having trouble with generic abstract classes and multiple parameters. In brief, I have a database table with a composite key defined by ProductAttributeEntity.class and ProductAttributeEntityPk.class, where ProductAttributeEntityPk.class is the composite key. I am struggling to pass ProductAttributeEntityPk.class into the abstract class for the getById method, which gives me, “Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method” error.

How can I get around this problem?

**PS:** I am **new** to java

Abstract DAO class (https://pastebin.com/n2FBQCg2)

```
package com.beetlehand.model.dao;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public abstract class AbstractDao<T, S> {

    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        if(this.entityManager == null) {
            this.entityManager = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit")
                .createEntityManager();
        }

        return this.entityManager;
    }

    public abstract T getById(S id);
    public abstract T getOneBy(Map<String, Object> params);
    public abstract List<T> getBy(String predicates, Map<String, Object> params);
    public abstract List<T> getBy(String predicates, Map<String, Object> params, String orderBy);
    public abstract List<T> getBy(String predicates, Map<String, Object> params, String orderBy
            , Integer limit);
    public abstract List<T> getBy(String predicates, Map<String, Object> params, String orderBy
            , Integer limit, Integer offset);

    public abstract Long count();
    public abstract Long countBy(String predicates, Map<String, Object> params);
}
```

DAO class (https://pastebin.com/tkMYLVZE)

```
package com.beetlehand.model.dao;

import com.beetlehand.model.ProductAttributeEntity;
import com.beetlehand.model.ProductAttributeEntityPk;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ProductAttributeDao extends AbstractDao<ProductAttributeEntity, ProductAttributeEntityPk> {

    public ProductAttributeEntity getById(ProductAttributeEntityPk id) {
        if (id == null) return null;
        return getEntityManager().find(ProductAttributeEntity.class, id);
    }
    
    /** other methods implementation **/

}
```

Entity classes (https://pastebin.com/5YySBt7X, https://pastebin.com/8rwD4kec)

```
package com.beetlehand.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product_attribute", schema = "beetlehand", catalog = "")
@IdClass(ProductAttributeEntityPK.class)
public class ProductAttributeEntity {
    private int productId;
    private int attributeValueId;

/** getter, setters, equals and hashcode implementation **/

}


package com.beetlehand.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ProductAttributeEntityPK implements Serializable {
    private int productId;
    private int attributeValueId;

/** getter, setters, equals and hashcode implementation **/
}
```

Comment: One of the 6 methods you've written in your definition of AbstractDao isn't in ProductAttributeDao. You haven't pasted the full class, so it's not possible to tell from what you've pasted which one(s) you're missing.

Comment: @rzwitserloot - On StackOverflow, there is a limit on placing how much code in a question. Hence the code fragment. I have now given links to the complete code.

Comment: The code you pasted cannot possibly produce that error, and especially not at runtime.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made a rookie mistake. I was editing the wrong file. I noticed the error after posting the code and forgot to update the question—eye fatigue.